# Comparing collections and counting duplicates using LINQ and C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have two similar objects in my system.

- LeadImportViewModel
- LeadGridViewModel

I need to populate the `QtyDuplicates` field in my `LeadImportViewModel` collection, which should show the quantity of corresponding records in the LeadGridViewModel collection where the  `CompanyNameStripped` value is identical.

```
public class LeadImportViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string CompanyNameStripped { get; set; }
    public int QtyDuplicates{ get; set; }
}

public class LeadGridViewModel
{
    public int LeadId { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string CompanyNameStripped { get; set; }
}
```

The collection is created as follows:

```
var coll = (from t1 in db.Leads_Staging
                    select new LeadImportViewModel
                        {
                            Id = t1.Id,
                            CompanyName = t1.CompanyName,
                            CompanyNameStripped = t1.CompanyNameStripped,

                        });
```

What would be the most efficient way to do this using LINQ/C#?

Comment: Are you just trying to find the intersecting IDs?

Comment: @JonSkeet No - just records where the CompanyNameStripped value is identical. Apologies - I missed this out of the question.

Comment: How do you want to poluate a string field with a _quantity_ and where's the collection?

Comment: @TimSchmelter This is a valid point. Fixed and added simple collection query.

Comment: You want the number of LeadGridViewModel records where the CompanyNameStripped is identical - to what? Identical to the LeadImportViewModel's CompanyNameStripped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `ForEach` and `Count` methods:

```
List<LeadImportViewModel> leadImportViewModelList = new List<LeadImportViewModel>();
List<LeadGridViewModel> leadGridViewModelList = new List<LeadGridViewModel>();

leadImportViewModelList.ForEach(vm => vm.QtyDuplicates 
    = leadGridViewModelList.Count(
    gv => gv.CompanyNameStripped = vm.CompanyNameStripped));
```

Comment: This has a disadvantage of having O(n^2) time complexity.

Comment: It's a good answer but add additional processing time. I went for a computed column instead.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you just need:

```
var count = leadImports.Select(x => x.CompanyNameStripped))
                       .Intersect(leadGrids.Select(x => x.CompanyNameStripped)))
                       .Count();
```

Or:

```
var names = new HashSet<string>(leadImports.Select(x => x.CompanyNameStripped));
var count = leadGrids.Count(x => names.Contains(x.CompanyNameStripped));
```

Comment: Hi Jon. Thanks for the response. Is it best just to iterate this for each item in the collection?

Comment: @Jon: what about using a `Lookup` and joining to `QtyDuplicates`?

Comment: @Nick: It's not clear what you mean. You wanted a count, and this gives you a count...

Answer (score 1):

`list.Select(a => a.CompanyNameStripped).Intersect(list2.Select(b => b.CompanyNameStripped).Count()`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var coll = (from t1 in db.Leads_Staging
                select new LeadImportViewModel
                    {
                        Id = t1.Id,
                        CompanyName = t1.CompanyName,
                        CompanyNameStripped = t1.CompanyNameStripped,
                        QtyDuplicates = db.LeadGridViewModel.Count(
                                        gv => gv.CompanyNameStripped == t1.CompanyNameStripped)
                    });
```